# Menu has > symbol

Tags: joomla-3.x, bootstrap

My bottom menu in the footer position has a greater than symbol (>) or chevron that appears before every menu item.

The menu appears at the footer of this website: https://www.brettvachon.com/

I would like to remove this symbol. I've tried navbar-collapse in the Menu Class Suffix as well as setting Start Level and End Level to 1 in the Menu Module options. This doesn't change anything though.

How do I remove the > symbol from the menu items?

[image: footer image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site where people can view the issue?

Comment: I've gone ahead and added the link. Also the effect happens on the sidebar module of my about page as well: https://www.brettvachon.com/about

Answer (score 0):

**templates/masterbootstrap/css/template.min.css**

line 108

```
.module-content ul li::before { 
content:"\e080";
font-family:glyphicons halflings 
}
```

Remove

```
content:"\e080";
```

Comment: I looked in the documentation to see if there was an override, but it contained no override information. If you update this template you may have to reference back to this question to remove it again. Unless someone knows this template and how this can be accomplished.

Comment: Surely you can do a custom CSS file? In which case you just need to be more specific e.g. `body .module-content UL li::before` then do `content: none;`

Comment: If you can't do a custom CSS file then you'll need to create a plugin to add a CSS file manually so you can still update the template without breaking it

Comment: I can use custom CSS in /scss/template/_custom.scss . But when I tried adding `.module-content ul li::before    {    content: ""!important;   }` this didn't work. I ended up deleting the line in template.min.css